# Парсинг бинарного файла

Tags: c++, fstream

Необходимо распарсить файл. Формат данных более-менее приемлимый: экспорт заявок, размер  файлов 1-25 мб, в каждой строке до символа ':' тэг, после него данные, строки кончаются 0x0D 0x0A, заявки отделены 0x0C).

Читал бы построчно, но проблема в символах  0x00, которых понатыкано очень много и в разных местах и последовательностях (да и 0x0A 0x0D местами 10-20 подряд).

Поэтому файл пробую читать как бинарный, для проверки пишу содержимое в другой файл.

Под *debug* нет проблем, в конце чтения выставляются `EOF` и `FAIL`, в конце записи почему-то `BAD`.

Под `release` данные пишутся, но в конце записи все флаги не выставлены,
в конце файла многочисленные символы 0x00 (для Unicode при сколько-нибудь крупном файле, странно - для мелочи в 1-100 строк такое не происходит) или вообще мусор в разнобой (для multibyte).

1. В чём может быть проблема? Тестировал на исходном файле с экспортом заявок и на файле-тестовике, генерируемом `PrepareForTestBinary`. Пробовал включить исключения для потоков, но ничего интереснее `ios_base::failbit set ; iostream:1` не выдаёт.

У меня MS VS2010

Командная строка компилятора под *Release*:

```
/Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" 
/Gm- /EHsc /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\binread.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" 
/Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

Командная строка компилятора под `Debug`:

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" 
/Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\binread.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" 
/Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

Игры с опциями ничего не дали.

Вот код:

```
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define TCOUT std::cout
#else
#define TCOUT std::wcout

typedef std::basic_ios<TCHAR> tios;
typedef std::basic_ifstream<TCHAR> tifstream;
typedef std::basic_ofstream<TCHAR> tofstream;
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

//проверка флагов для потоков
void fState(tios &fs)
{
    TCOUT << _T("fail bad eof good\n");
    TCOUT << (fs.rdstate()&fs.failbit) << _T(" ; ") <<  (fs.rdstate()&fs.badbit)  << _T(" ; ") << (fs.rdstate()&fs.eofbit) << _T(" ; ") << (fs.rdstate()&fs.goodbit) << endl;
}

//Для тестирования генерируем исходный файл
void PrepareForTestBinary(tstring PATH)
{
    tofstream os;
    os.open (PATH, ios_base::binary ||ios_base::out);
    for (int i = 0; i<200000;i++) os << _T("0123456789") << '\0' << _T("ABCDEFGHIJ") << std::endl;
    os.close();
}
// Читаем и пишем 
void TestBinary(tstring inPATH,tstring outPATH)
{
    LONGLONG len;
    TCHAR * buffer;
    tifstream is;
    fState(is);
    is.open (inPATH, ios_base::binary ||ios_base::in );
    fState(is);
    is.seekg (0, ios::end);
    len = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    buffer = new TCHAR [len];
    fState(is);
    is.read (buffer,len);
    fState(is);
    is.close();
    tofstream os;
    fState(os);
    os.open (outPATH, ios_base::binary ||ios_base::out);
    fState(os);
    os.write(buffer,len);
    fState(os);
    os.close();
    delete[] buffer;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
{
    PrepareForTestBinary(_T("D:\\!binary\\1\\11"));
    TestBinary(_T("D:\\!binary\\1\\11"),_T("D:\\!binary\\1\\22"));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При этом такой способ никаких проблем не даёт (но и проблем моих с парсом не решает):

```
void TestBinary_bufferExch(tstring inPATH,tstring outPATH)
{
    tifstream is;
    tofstream os;
    is.open (inPATH, ios_base::binary || ios_base::in );
    os.open (outPATH,ios_base::binary ||ios_base::out);
    os << is.rdbuf();
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Сопутствующие вопросы:

2. Как оптимально вырезать из потока все символы '0x00' ? Пока ничего умнее не придумал, как
   в цикле посимвольно сравнивать и все отличные от '0x00' писать в другой буфер(или поток).
3. Как вообще правильно читать поток, содержимое и формат которого не известны?
4. Прошу ткнуть в мало-мальски грамотный парсер(код пощупать).

**Обновление**

Пробовал даже так, никаких изменений.

```
void TestBinary(tstring inPATH,tstring outPATH)
{
    LONGLONG len = 0;
    TCHAR * buffer = 0;
    tifstream is;
    fState(is);
    is.open (inPATH, ios_base::binary ||ios_base::in );
    fState(is);
    is.seekg (0, ios::end);
    len = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    buffer = new TCHAR [len];
    memset(buffer,0,len);
    fState(is);
    is.read (buffer,len);
    fState(is);
    is.close();
    tofstream os;
    fState(os);
    os.open (outPATH, ios_base::binary ||ios_base::out);
    fState(os);
    os.write(buffer,len);
    fState(os);
    os.close();
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

**Обновление 2**

Провёл доп. исследования. Проблема возникает только при наличии в файле 0x0D 0x0A (`endl` помещённый в поток). При наличии '\0' (0x00) проблема не возникает.

Comment: Вообще различие поведения Debug-Release часто связаны с неинициализорованными переменными. Все переменные инициализованы нулями?

Comment: memset(buffer,'0',len);

Comment: В вопрос этот код. И что, кстати, отладчик показывает?

Comment: А вы не думали просто воспользоваться функционалом из бустов для решения этой задачи?

Comment: С отладчиком просматриваю, пока ничего криминального не вижу. На счёт буста - мало знаком с ним, только начинаю. Пока хочу решить вопрос стандартными средствами, к тому же проблема заинтересовала...

Comment: @AntonCooler То есть все(!) переменные инициализорованы и в отладчике все работает? Хм... Подземный стук.

Comment: Странно то, что в debug  в отладчике видно значение переменных , lenght определяется верно. В release значения не вижу.

Comment: @AntonCooler: В релизе переменные могут быть выкинуты нафиг оптимизатором. Используйте отладочную печать.

Comment: @AntonCooler В вашем коде мне кажется я вижу одну не точность. Побитовое или должно писаться через один символ | ios_base::binary |ios_base::in. В вашем случае это операция ИЛИ.

Comment: @Unick Спасибо большое, проблема решилась! Моя невнимательность = неопределённое поведение :)

Comment: @VladD Просветите пожалуйста насчёт отладочной печати.

Comment: @AntonCooler: Ну. просто выводите значение нужной переменной на печать при помощи `printf` или через `cout`.

Comment: @VladD О, это я в первую очередь делал. А то я уже подумал о неком новом средстве. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ помог Вам, тогда пометьте его как верный(галочка рядом с ответом). Это нужно для того, чтобы вопрос не висел в не отвеченных, а также в качестве награды отвечающему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде мне кажется я вижу одну неточность. "Побитовое ИЛИ" должно писаться через один символ | (ios_base::binary |ios_base::in). В вашем случае это операция "логического ИЛИ" и результат его скорее всего равен 1 для обоих файлов.